# Makefile for linking an extern global

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

I'm trying to use the `g_struct` variable that's defined in `struct.cpp` and declared in `struct.hpp` inside the `test.cpp`, but the linking fails. Why is that?

```cpp
// test.cpp

#include "struct.hpp"

int main(void)
{
    g_struct.a = 1;
    return 0;
}
```

```cpp
// struct.cpp

#include "struct.hpp"

Struct g_struct;
```

```cpp
// struct.hpp

#pragma once

struct Struct {
    int a;
};

extern Struct g_struct;
```

```
# Makefile

CC = g++

all: struct.o test

test: test.cpp
    $(CC) -o test test.cpp

struct.o: struct.cpp
    $(CC) -c -o struct.o struct.cpp

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -f *.o test
```

Linking error:

```
$ make
g++ -c -o struct.o struct.cpp
g++ -o test test.cpp
/tmp/ccgSoJhd.o: In function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0xd): undefined reference to `g_struct'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:6: recipe for target 'test' failed
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

If I link without the `-c` flag, I get:

```
$ make
g++ -o struct.o struct.cpp
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:9: recipe for target 'struct.o' failed
make: *** [struct.o] Error 1
```

Comment: You didn't link `struct.o` into the final executable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to link `struct.o`, which has `Struct g_struct;`.

```
test: test.cpp
    $(CC) -o test test.cpp struct.o
```